# Width limitation wx.Choice breaks on Linux

Tags: python, linux, wxpython

I am making a DB browser, the computer it needs to run on is really slow and is on Linux Ubuntu. I already had a lot of issues installing libraries for it to run on this computer, and because of this I have a slightly different version of wxPython on Linux (4.0.7 instead of 4.1.1) and I have no idea why since I tried all the. I don't often have access to it so I did the whole thing on my computer on Windows (I know, bad idea) then I test it once or twice a week on site. I design the app with wxFormBuilder which generates a python script. The thing is that wxPython doesn't render widgets the same way on Windows or on Linux, which is understandable, but now the app is not usable on Linux :

I had to put  a max width on wx.Choice objects because their default width is set to what can be chosen and it turns out the choices are from the database and there's a risk that having multiple wx.Choice in a line will make the window too wide if the strings of the database are too wide.

Here's a code example I wrote based on what wxFormBuilder generates :

```
import wx

class Window(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"test", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.DefaultSize, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        choices = ["long string to demonstrate example", "shorter string", "shrt"]

        self.choice1 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, choices, wx.CB_SORT )
        self.choice1.SetSelection( 0 )
        self.choice1.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 100,-1 ) )
        sizer.Add( self.choice1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )
        
        self.choice2 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, choices, wx.CB_SORT )
        self.choice2.SetSelection( 1 )
        self.choice2.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 100,-1 ) )
        sizer.Add( self.choice2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )
        
        self.choice3 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, choices, wx.CB_SORT )
        self.choice3.SetSelection( 2 )
        self.choice3.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 100,-1 ) )
        sizer.Add( self.choice3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
    
    def __del__(self) :
        pass

app = wx.App(False) 
frame = Window(None) 
#start the applications
frame.Show() 
app.MainLoop()
```

What it does on Window 10 :
[image]

What it does on Linux Ubuntu (22 I believe) :
[image]

Description of the issue : on Linux, it seems that only the rifht part of the full wx.Choice object is shown.
Also the click detection area of these glitched wx.Choice are bigger than what's displayed : it looks like they are taking all the space that they would if they weren't width limited.

For now I'll just remove the width limit but it would be nice if I could have it on linux, thanks for your help.

Edit : added a proper example with code.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK))

Comment: Or at the very least show us the code that defines the display.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot about it. I'm adding this as soon as I can

Comment: I added a proper example

Comment: Looks like setting an arbitrary size confuses wx.Choice, probably ComboBox too. Trying to set an extrastyle of wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT or a style wx.ALIGN_LEFT doesn't seem to help either. Consider reporting it as a bug and see if you get any joy.